# Process Builder curl returns nothing for an API Response

Tags: java, api, curl, output, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to execute curl from my Java code and it returns nothing. I tried the same curl command from Terminal on my Mac and it works ok and creates the file based on curl output. curloutput.txt is blank and file1.txt is not created after I run the program because it does not get anything back.

```
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/curl", "-H" ,"'Accept: application/json'", "-H","'Content-Type: application/json'",
  "-X", "POST", "-d","'{\"args\":", "{\"uid\":", uid,"\"token\":",token,
  "\"api-token\":",apitoken,"\"json-strict-mode\":","false,", "\"json-verbose-response\":","false}}'",
   url,">>","file1.txt"); 

Process p;

try
{
    process.redirectOutput(new File("curloutput.txt"));
    p = process.start();
    p.waitFor();//added based on Earlybird's suggestion

}
catch (IOException e)
{   System.out.print("error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: After starting the process you need to wait until it finishes. In your case (from the code snippet), application terminates immediately after the process gets created.

Comment: I added p.waitFor() after p = process.start(); but still I dont get any output

Comment: Try http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html  Using the ProcessBuilder section